# Anonymous User: You are not authorized to access this page. Permissions OK

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, access-denied

After rebuilding permissions, running cron, flushing caches, dotting the i's and crossing the t's, I've come the the bug report zone. I'm out of ideas, at this point:

-All pages on my site are unavailable to the anonymous user, even though they function perfectly for all other users/roles!

-The header, sidebar, and nav functions all load as they should, but the actual content of the page is replaced with a simple statement of "You are not authorized to access this page."

I feel as though there's something simple I'm missing, but I'm just not finding it. I've been all up and down this site and a few others, to no avail. Is there some other means for checking/correcting this? Dblog registers an "access denied" event, but with no detail to go on. Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Running PHP 5.2.17 with Drupal 6.22 on Bluehost, for what it's worth.

Edit: I did check for user 0. 0 was missing, so I went ahead and added him (or is it her?) and re-ran the usual housekeeping (cron, update.php, rebuild permissions) ...But still no love. I had a look at .htaccess, but I must confess that I'm not sure what I'm looking for in there. Nothing appears to be related to user access, anonymous or otherwise. For what it's worth, this is on the development site. The live site does exactly what it's supposed to, and has exactly the same host, settings and modules (as far as I can tell). This suggests to me that there's something I'm missing.... If they really WERE the same, they'd work the same! ;) Thanks for the suggestions so far! I have other modules to review, but they're waiting on this issue...

Comment: did you look at the .htaccess file?

Comment: Check that there's an entry in the `users` table with a `uid` of 0 (the anonymous user). Drupal 6 throws it's toys out if that's missing

Answer (score 3):

FIXED! I finally uncovered this:

```
INSERT  INTO  node_access
  (nid ,gid ,realm ,grant_view, grant_update , grant_delete)
  VALUES ( '0',  '0',  'all',  '1',  '0',  '0')
```

I took a look at the node_access table, and sure enough, there was no entry for the anonymous user! I don't know why it went missing, but the above query resumed content access for the anonymous user.
  My persisting issue is that the dblog has "access denied" entries accompanying normal page loads, but I guess that's a new question, eh?

Answer (score 0):

My solution when I had that that problem was this.

1. Backup the database (of course)
2. Set up the permission of the search block
3. Rebuild the permissions admin/people/permissions
4. Then go to admin/config/search/settings and go to Default search module and select node instead of user.

Hope it helps for someone.